# is it possible to span multiples pages in multicolumn?

Tags: page-breaking, longtable

I have documents generated like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{7cm}|p{7cm}|}
  \multicolumn{2}{p{14cm}}{
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipiscing elit. Ut scelerisque metus eget velit rhoncus
    cursus. Aenean eleifend, lectus id venenatis pretium, sapien
    ligula auctor mauris, at condimentum dui nulla quis nisi. Morbi ut
    massa sapien, et tincidunt dolor. Ut vitae ante quam. Cum sociis
    natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
    ridiculus mus. Maecenas ultrices lobortis nunc, sed porttitor
    dolor dapibus in. Sed commodo auctor luctus. Duis at velit
    fringilla sem ultricies aliquet. Morbi venenatis venenatis turpis,
    et congue quam venenatis at. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et
    magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam
    elementum consequat nisi, sed venenatis dolor ultrices ac.

    Sed nisi urna, sollicitudin sit amet hendrerit lacinia, porta at
    tortor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur posuere felis at risus
    feugiat at ultrices velit imperdiet. Phasellus vulputate porttitor
    ipsum, in mattis odio dictum at. Pellentesque in sapien quis nisl
    ultrices accumsan. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut odio neque, tempor
    sed semper ut, auctor in dolor. Praesent id tempus quam. Donec
    viverra sodales nisi quis ultrices. Proin sit amet nulla vitae est
    vehicula porta. Sed dignissim condimentum sagittis.

    Integer eros nibh, consectetur id commodo luctus, tempus eu
    magna. Duis vulputate ante egestas purus volutpat aliquet. Nunc
    hendrerit commodo congue. Cras orci tellus, pretium in dapibus id,
    pretium ac justo. Aenean a urna augue. Suspendisse
    potenti. Vivamus molestie, odio non aliquet imperdiet, nulla
    tellus adipiscing arcu, vitae malesuada turpis quam nec elit. Ut
    et orci eu arcu pretium feugiat vitae vitae nunc. Suspendisse
    ornare interdum rutrum. Nulla nec arcu a nunc tincidunt
    hendrerit. Nullam diam massa, posuere vitae lacinia vitae, tempus
    et odio.

    Pellentesque dictum rutrum sem eu elementum. Suspendisse ultrices
    dui a neque congue lobortis. Pellentesque vestibulum pretium
    aliquet. Sed euismod iaculis tellus, ac posuere justo sollicitudin
    vestibulum. Phasellus tincidunt semper euismod. Aenean id quam nec
    augue viverra elementum quis a sapien. Cras porttitor arcu id arcu
    cursus sed eleifend justo malesuada. Mauris diam lorem, tincidunt
    vitae pulvinar non, luctus in orci. Donec lectus felis, lobortis
    eget vulputate eget, eleifend nec leo. Integer vel tincidunt
    augue. Duis tristique feugiat mauris, eu eleifend sem ultricies
    sit amet. Sed bibendum turpis sed est faucibus gravida sagittis
    magna vulputate. Vestibulum luctus laoreet velit, et euismod ante
    vestibulum a.

    Ut sit amet nibh at sapien pulvinar cursus id sed lorem. Phasellus
    ultricies ornare facilisis. Fusce accumsan condimentum aliquam. Aenean
    ac lectus at lorem mollis blandit ac at lorem. Integer bibendum, leo
    in varius suscipit, massa dui lobortis ligula, in tincidunt augue
    velit in nulla. Cras sit amet ipsum sem, at fermentum sem. Integer
    neque nunc, tempus et tempor quis, ultricies nec nisl. Maecenas
    pretium dolor ac elit cursus facilisis.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut
    scelerisque metus eget velit rhoncus cursus. Aenean eleifend,
    lectus id venenatis pretium, sapien ligula auctor mauris, at
    condimentum dui nulla quis nisi. Morbi ut massa sapien, et
    tincidunt dolor. Ut vitae ante quam. Cum sociis natoque penatibus
    et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas
    ultrices lobortis nunc, sed porttitor dolor dapibus in. Sed
    commodo auctor luctus. Duis at velit fringilla sem ultricies
    aliquet. Morbi venenatis venenatis turpis, et congue quam
    venenatis at. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
    parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam elementum
    consequat nisi, sed venenatis dolor ultrices ac.

    Sed nisi urna, sollicitudin sit amet hendrerit lacinia, porta at
    tortor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur posuere felis at risus
    feugiat at ultrices velit imperdiet. Phasellus vulputate porttitor
    ipsum, in mattis odio dictum at. Pellentesque in sapien quis nisl
    ultrices accumsan. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut odio neque, tempor
    sed semper ut, auctor in dolor. Praesent id tempus quam. Donec
    viverra sodales nisi quis ultrices. Proin sit amet nulla vitae est
    vehicula porta. Sed dignissim condimentum sagittis.

    Integer eros nibh, consectetur id commodo luctus, tempus eu
    magna. Duis vulputate ante egestas purus volutpat aliquet. Nunc
    hendrerit commodo congue. Cras orci tellus, pretium in dapibus id,
    pretium ac justo. Aenean a urna augue. Suspendisse
    potenti. Vivamus molestie, odio non aliquet imperdiet, nulla
    tellus adipiscing arcu, vitae malesuada turpis quam nec elit. Ut
    et orci eu arcu pretium feugiat vitae vitae nunc. Suspendisse
    ornare interdum rutrum. Nulla nec arcu a nunc tincidunt
    hendrerit. Nullam diam massa, posuere vitae lacinia vitae, tempus
    et odio.

    Pellentesque dictum rutrum sem eu elementum. Suspendisse ultrices
    dui a neque congue lobortis. Pellentesque vestibulum pretium
    aliquet. Sed euismod iaculis tellus, ac posuere justo sollicitudin
    vestibulum. Phasellus tincidunt semper euismod. Aenean id quam nec
    augue viverra elementum quis a sapien. Cras porttitor arcu id arcu
    cursus sed eleifend justo malesuada. Mauris diam lorem, tincidunt
    vitae pulvinar non, luctus in orci. Donec lectus felis, lobortis
    eget vulputate eget, eleifend nec leo. Integer vel tincidunt
    augue. Duis tristique feugiat mauris, eu eleifend sem ultricies
    sit amet. Sed bibendum turpis sed est faucibus gravida sagittis
    magna vulputate. Vestibulum luctus laoreet velit, et euismod ante
    vestibulum a.

    Ut sit amet nibh at sapien pulvinar cursus id sed lorem. Phasellus
    ultricies ornare facilisis. Fusce accumsan condimentum
    aliquam. Aenean ac lectus at lorem mollis blandit ac at
    lorem. Integer bibendum, leo in varius suscipit, massa dui
    lobortis ligula, in tincidunt augue velit in nulla. Cras sit amet
    ipsum sem, at fermentum sem. Integer neque nunc, tempus et tempor
    quis, ultricies nec nisl. Maecenas pretium dolor ac elit cursus
    facilisis.}

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The output results in a single page, is it possible to make `multicolumn` span over the necessary pages? I am already using longtable, but given the text is inside a multicolumn, the result is only one page and missing text, any way of making it work using multicolumn or a workaround?

Comment: A table cell can never be split across pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the first answer has said, if it isn't really a table, then `multicol` may do the trick. If your real examples are more tabular in nature, then allowing page breaks mid row isn't an unreasonable request but it's pretty hard to achieve in general (think about a row that may contain `p`-cells, cells with unbreakable images, cells with single line `c` or `l` etc) finding a good place to break each cell in the row and re-constitute the table is hard. I have a feeling I implemented something once, but it was never robust enough to use. So short answer to the question as posed is "no", sorry. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `multicol` package for this:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```